# setInterval() not repeating. Works only 1 time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to have a div's left property change by its self - one every second when your hovering over so I made this:

```
$("div.scroll_left").hover(function(){
    var left_num = $('div.license_video').css("left")
    var left_num1 = parseInt(left_num, 10) - 1;
    var timerID = setInterval(alert(left_num1), 1000);
    //var timerID = setInterval(slideleft(left_num1), 1000);
},function(){
    clearInterval(timerID);
});
//function slideleft(left_num){
    //$('.license_video').css('left', left_num + "%");
//}
```

In theory you would think it repeat till you move your cursor off which clears the interval. When I hover over it does it one time and never repeats (there are no errors). Then when I hover off it gives a error "Uncaught ReferenceError: timerID is not defined"

Comment: timerId is defined within the scope of the .hover(function ()... Try defining timerId before $("div.scroll_left")... (I don;t think this address the setInterval repeating question, but it is a start).

Comment: You might want to think about using [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`setInterval` isn't working at all. You aren't passing it a function as the first argument.

You are calling `alert` **immediately** and trying to use it's return value as the function to repeat.

```
var timerID = setInterval(function () { alert(left_num1) }, 1000);
```

Comment: Except remove the `alert()` and put the `slideleft()` function back in.  Nobody wants alerts on an interval.

Comment: That's not working with setInterval(function() {$('.license_video').css('left', left_num + "%")}, 1000); that's why I wasen't using it before. Also I'm still getting a "Uncaught ReferenceError: timerID is not defined" error

Comment: @RosengustaGarrett my answer explains how to solve the "Uncaught ReferenceError" problem.

Answer (score 17):

So you've got two different problems here:

```
// (1) timerID needs to be defined in a scope accessible to both hover callbacks
var timerID = null;

$("div.scroll_left").hover(function(){
    var left_num = $('div.license_video').css("left")
    var left_num1 = parseInt(left_num, 10) - 1;

    // (2) Pass a *function* to setInterval
    timerID = setInterval(function () {
        alert(left_num1)
    }, 1000);
}, function(){
    clearInterval(timerID);
    timerID = null;
});
```

When you write

```
setInterval(alert(left_num1), 1000);
// or
setInterval(slideleft(left_num1), 1000);
```

you are passing the value returned by calling `alert()` or `slideleft()` (respectively) to `setInterval`. You are *not* passing the function itself.

Answer (score 7):

You are assigning `null` to be the function to call. Why? Because you called `alert` and assigned its return value to the setInterval parameter.

Instead, use an anonymous function:

```
setInterval(function() {doStuff();},1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Very easy ;-) ... i love jquery, no matter a version... u need javascript pure is send pm me is can help.

```js
umavez = 0;
setInterval(function() {
 if (umavez == 0) {
      for (x=0;x<10;x++) { 
        $('div.test').append('<div>'+x+'</div>');
      }
    }
  umavez = 1;
}, 500);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">Linha:</div>
```